# Transaction within a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is the following the correct way to use transactions within a cursor:

```
SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT ON;

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT * FROM @ordersToProcess;
OPEN cur;

DECLARE @OrderId int;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @OrderId;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN;
        EXEC process_order @OrderId;
        COMMIT TRAN;
        DEALLOCATE cur;                 
        SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
        DEALLOCATE cur;
        SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF;
        THROW;
    END CATCH;  

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @OrderId;
END;
```

Comment: You can't deallocate your cursor where you are doing it now. You are still inside your cursor. And close it first too.

Comment: Why do you deallocating cursor while iterating on it?

Comment: I would prefer to get rid of the cursor entirely but that is a big can of worms. However, your code has a problem. You are deallocating your cursor inside the loop. And you never close it...

Comment: Suppose the cursor has 500 records, and it fails on the 10 th record. Do you want the first 9 records to be written and the others not ? Or do you want no record written when one fails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You have this code:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN;
        EXEC process_order @OrderId;
        COMMIT TRAN;
        DEALLOCATE cur;                 
        SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF;
    END TRY
    . . .
```

This runs one time through the loop, deallocates the cursor and then . . . well, you have a problem on the second time through the loop.

I think you intend to dealloc *after* the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Deallocate and Close after the cursor has finished:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT * FROM @ordersToProcess;
OPEN cur;
DECLARE @OrderId int;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @OrderId;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN;
        EXEC process_order @OrderId;
        COMMIT TRAN;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
        THROW;
    END CATCH;  

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @OrderId;
END;

BEGIN TRY      
    CLOSE Cursor1
    DEALLOCATE Cursor1                                  
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 --Do nothing
END CATCH
```